# running python code in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I have just started learning python.How do I run python code (having a function in python code) using powershell? I am able to run python code having no function in powershell.
*I have saved the python code in mystuff folder.* I have tried to run it in powershell (i typed this in powershell-   `c:\users\pbesra\mystuff> python exam.py`  ,but it gives nothing in return and also it doesn't show any error.When I type- `c:\users\pbesra\mystuff> python exam.py`, It gives- `c:\users\pbesra\mystuff>` in return.Please help me.
I have written the code from ""Learn Python the hard way" book
 exam.py

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1,arg2=args
    print("arg1:%r,arg2:%r" %(arg1,arg2))
#ok,that *args is actually pointless,we can just do this
def print_two_again(arg1,arg2):
    print("arg1:%r,arg2:%r" %(arg1,arg2))
#this just takes one argument
def print_one(arg1):
    print("arg1:%r" %arg1)
#this one takes no arguments
def print_none():
    print("I got nothing.")

print_two("Zed","Shaw")
print_two_again("Zed","Shaw")
print_one("First!")
print_none()
```

Comment: Are you calling your function at the bottom of your file? After the definition of the function?

Comment: Can you show us `exam.py`?

Comment: Does it run from dos command prompt?

Comment: Thank you  shahkalpesh,I am able to run it in command prompt. :)

Comment: However, it is strange that it didnt run from powershell. I tried and it did work for me. Try running python from powershell without any argument to see if you are able to see the REPL as you would from dos prompt.